# SQL Server stored procedures calls require variable declaration (but already declared)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, xbrl

I have a few stored procedures which I call in this order.

[image]

So, from the first stored procedure, `importTaxonomy` I call `parseXBRL` and from `parseXBRL` I call `createTaxonomyStructure`.

But in this flow, when the code of the last stored procedure is executed I get an error.

`Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@temporaryTable".`

Below you can find the first few lines code of this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createTaxonomyStructure @taxonomy_table nvarchar(max), @debug bit = 0  
AS

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @temporaryTable TABLE (taxonomyLine NVARCHAR(MAX))      -- declared a temporary table to avoid creating a Dynamic Query with the entire cursor, but just with the temporary table
DECLARE @taxonomyLine NVARCHAR(MAX)     -- variable that will store one line of the taxonomy

    SET @statement = 'INSERT INTO @temporaryTable SELECT taxText FROM ' + @taxonomy_table   -- statement that will import the taxonomy in the temporary table

EXEC sp_executesql @statement           

DECLARE taxonomyCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR        -- read each line in the taxonomy to parse afterwards
    SELECT taxonomyLine
    FROM @temporaryTable

OPEN taxonomyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM taxonomyCursor INTO @taxonomyLine               -- parsing each taxonomy line and extracting the values from important attributes
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @id_element NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @leaf_element NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT @id_element = (SELECT dbo.extract_IDElement(@taxonomyLine))
        SELECT @leaf_element = (SELECT dbo.extract_IDLeafElement(@taxonomyLine))

        SET @statement = 'UPDATE ' + @taxonomy_table + ' SET fullName = ''' + @id_element + ''', leafName = ''' + @leaf_element + '''';

        EXEC sp_executesql @statement

    END
```

I do declare this variable, but I still get the error and I don't understand why.

How can I get over this error?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code for createTaxonomyStructure sp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is here:

```
SET @statement = 'INSERT INTO @temporaryTable SELECT taxText FROM ' + @taxonomy_table   -- statement that will import the taxonomy in the temporary table

EXEC sp_executesql @statement
```

change it to

```
set @statement = 'select taxText from ' + @taxonomy_table

insert into @temporaryTable
exec sp_executesql @statement
```

The error is happening because in the scope of executing `@statement` there's no variable table `@temporaryTable`.